# Расскажите что такое CriticalFinalizerObject, только попроще

Tags: .net

прочитал https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.constrainedexecution.criticalfinalizerobject?view=net-5.0 и ничего не понял по правде

Comment: А вот это читали про собственно CER: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/performance/constrained-execution-regions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрим по вашей ссылке:

> Классы, производные от CriticalFinalizerObject класса, неявно
> обрабатываются как область ограниченного выполнения (CER).

Дальше смотрим, что такое [CER](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/performance/constrained-execution-regions):

> Область ограниченного выполнения (CER) является одной из составляющих
> механизма создания надежного управляемого кода. В этой области
> общеязыковая среда выполнения (CLR) не может выдавать
> специализированные исключения, препятствующие полному выполнению
> заключенного в эту область кода. В этой области не может выполняться
> пользовательский код, в результате которого могут возникать
> специализированные исключения.

В общем, насколько я понял, наследование класса от `CriticalFinalizerObject` гарантирует вам, что код такого класса будет исполняться в этой самой `CER` и ничто не помешает в этом случае сработать блоку `finally`. В общем случае в `.NET` может произойти много всякого разного, что не даст сработать финализатору класса. А этот механизм даёт гарантию.